# Unterschied zwischen "ich freue mich" und "es freut mich"

Tags: difference

> (a) Ich freue mich, dich wiederzusehen.
>
> (b) Es freut mich, dich wiederzusehen.

Es scheint mir, dass die beiden Sätze genau dieselbe Bedeutung haben. Ist das so, oder gibt es doch einen kleinen Unterschied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Auch](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/18387/5437) aus meiner mitteldeutschen Sicht würden beide Sätze vom Empfänger in derselben Weise verstanden werden.

Allerdings wirken beide Formulierungen etwas formal. <sup>[1]</sup> Neben der großen Übereinstimmung (98%) könnte man an den Rändern der Überlappung Differenzen gerade in dieser Hinsicht sehen: die Formulierung mit dem *Es freut mich* wirkt etwas weniger persönlich.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>
Weniger formal klänge z.B. der Satz *Schön dich wiederzusehen!*.

Answer (score 1):

Ja, beide Sätze haben die gleiche Bedeutung. (Das ist wenigstens mein Gefühl als süddeutscher Muttersprachler.)

Answer (score 1):

Als englischer gebürtiger deutscher studierter verstehe ich die beide Sätze anders.
a) is there an an implied "darauf" here, as in looking forward to seeing you again?
ich freue mich (darauf), dich wiederzusehen.
b) i'm glad to be seeing you (right now) once again.